# Why i get an Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\UwAmp\www\v.php on line 11?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

i have an PHP code like below.
i use an array, looping, and function in my PHP code

```
<?php
    $array_rows = array( 50, 60, 50, 50 );
    $array_cols = array( 30, 20, 70, 30, 60 );
    $costs = array(
        array( 16, 16, 13, 22, 17 ),
        array( 14, 14, 13, 19, 15 ),
        array( 19, 19, 20, 23, 50 ),
        array( 50, 12, 50, 15, 11 )
    );

    function diff($j, $len, $is_row, $res[3]) {
        $i, $c, max($min1), $min2 = $min1, $min_p = -1;
        for($i=0; $i<$len; ++$i) {
            if(($is_row) ? $col_done[$i] : $row_done[$i]) continue;
            $c = ($is_row) ? $costs[$j][$i] : $costs[$i][$j];
            if($c < $min1) {
                $min2 = $min1;
                $min1 = $c;
                $min_p = $i;
            }
            else if($c < $min2) $min2 = $c;
        } 
        $res[0] = $min2 - $min1;
        $res[1] = $min1;
        $res[2] = $min_p;
    }

?>
```

but why I get an Error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in
>   C:\UwAmp\www\v.php on line 11

can somebody help my to fix my error code?

Comment: You should use the key when calling the function, not defining it.

Comment: You can't take `$res[3]` as a function parameter, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you use an IDE?  They can be helpful in solving some common errors in coding.

Comment: You're going to run into errors over the next few lines as well. Line 12 looks like javascript assignment syntax, which does not work with PHP. Then after that will be the unknown variables since they don't exist in scope...